# API Request not sending properly

Tags: node.js, swift, express, get

I am trying to make an API request from my Swift app to fetch the carpools a user is in based on their userid. I have a table in my database called `user_carpools` with columns `firebase_user_id` and `carpool_id`.

This is my get request:

```
app.get('/api/carpools/:firebase_user_id', async (req, res) => {
    const firebaseUserId = req.body.firebase_user_id;

    try {
        // Fetch carpools that the user is part of
        const query = `
            SELECT c.*
            FROM "carpools" c
            JOIN "user_carpools" uc ON c.carpool_id = uc.carpool_id
            WHERE uc.firebase_user_id = $1
        `;

        const queryResult = await db.query(query, [firebaseUserId]);
        const userCarpools = queryResult.rows;

        res.status(200).json(userCarpools);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
```

This is my function in Swift to make the request:

```swift
func getUserCarpools(completion: @escaping ([GroupT]?) -> Void) {
        // Check if there is a logged-in user
        guard let firebaseUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            // Handle the case where there is no logged-in user
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        // Define the API endpoint URL
        guard var apiUrlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://localhost/api/carpools/") else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        // Append firebaseUserId as a query parameter
        apiUrlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "firebaseUserId", value: firebaseUserId)]

        guard let apiUrl = apiUrlComponents.url else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        // Create a URLSession
        let session = URLSession.shared

        // Create a URLRequest
        var request = URLRequest(url: apiUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // Check for errors
            if let error = error {
                print("Error making request: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            // Check for a successful HTTP response
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("No HTTP response")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            print("HTTP Response Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

            guard (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                print("Error: Unexpected HTTP response status code")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            // Check if there is data
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Error: No data received")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            // Parse the JSON data
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let userCarpools = try decoder.decode([GroupT].self, from: data)
                print("User Carpools: \(userCarpools)")
                completion(userCarpools)
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }

        // Resume the task to make the request
        task.resume()
        print(firebaseUserId)
    }
```

This is my page where I use the function:

```swift
struct MyGroups: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = GroupsListViewModel()
    @State private var carpools: [GroupT]? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let carpools = carpools {
                List(carpools.indices) { index in
                    Text(carpools[index].carpoolName)
                }
            } else {
                Text("Loading...")
                    .onAppear {
                        vm.getUserCarpools { fetchedCarpools in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.carpools = fetchedCarpools
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Firebase user id is printing properly but when I print user carpools it just prints all the carpools in the database.